# MySQL user-defined variable in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I want to know if there is a way to use a user-defined variable in `WHERE` clause, as in this example:

```
SELECT id, location, @id := 10 FROM songs WHERE id = @id
```

This query runs with no errors but doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What are you expecting the query to do?

Comment: In the real scenario I want to define a variable to get LOCATE() offset of a substring in a field. I use it many times in the SELECT statement. The problem is that I want to show only results that have this offset greater than zero. I know that I can use another LOCATE() in WHERE clause, but why this variable doesn't work in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not far from what Mike E. proposed, but one statement:

```
SELECT id, location FROM songs, ( SELECT @id := 10 ) AS var WHERE id = @id;
```

I used similar queries to emulate window functions in MySQL. E.g. [Row sampling](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/05/row-sampling/) - just an example of using variables in the same statement

Comment: Subquery in the FROM clause... what a useful trick! Thank you! :)

Comment: Is there any possible way to check if UDV is not null then fire this Query? case explained in [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227972/mariadb-user-define-variable-throws-warning-if-it-is-empty/227975)

Comment: if where clause is string, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

From the MySQL manual page on [User Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html):

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed.

So you should separate the assignment from the select statement:

```
SET @id = 10;
SELECT id, location, @id FROM songs WHERE id = @id;
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure, but I've never seen anyone try to set a variable and use it in the same statement like you are.  Try:

```
SET @id := 10;
SELECT @id := 10 FROM songs WHERE id = @id;
```

or

```
SELECT @id := 10 FROM songs;
SELECT @id := 10 FROM songs WHERE id = @id;
```

I've used both, and they both seem to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me!

```
SET @identifier = 7;
SELECT * FROM test where identifier = @identifier;
```

Comment: this works equally well in MariaDb too, but surprisingly its not really that well documented.   this is surprising, considering how useful it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what about this.

Just like @PauloFreitas I needed some user defined variables to improve the readability and reduce operations in some large queries.
I ended up with queries like below, just created for demonstration purposes.
I define the variables first, then assign them in a nifty `IF()` statement in the WHERE clause, as that is executed before the SELECT part but is based on the row data. Then I'm able to use them anywhere.

```
CREATE TABLE `strings` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED,
  `string` VARCHAR(255)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

    INSERT INTO `strings` (`id`, `string`) VALUES
(1, "abcde"),
(2, "bcdef"),
(3, "cdefg"),
(4, "defgh"),
(5, "efghi");

-- Declare the variables:
SET @CDpos=-1;
SET @DEpos=-1;
```

---

**First SELECT Query**

Show usage of filling the variables with row data

```
SELECT
    `id`, 
    `string`,
    @CDpos AS `Position of "cd"`,
    @DEpos AS `Position of "de"`
FROM 
    `strings` 
WHERE 
    `id` = IF(
                (((@CDpos:=LOCATE("cd", `string`)) OR TRUE) 
                AND ((@DEpos:=LOCATE("de", `string`)) OR TRUE))
                , `id`
                , `id`
            );
```

| id | string | Position of "cd" | Position of "de" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcde | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | bcdef | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | cdefg | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | defgh | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | efghi | 0 | 0 |

---

**Second SELECT Query**

Now also use the variables in the WHERE to filter rows

```
SELECT
    `id`, 
    `string`,
    @CDpos AS `Position of "cd"`,
    @DEpos AS `Position of "de"`
FROM 
    `strings` 
WHERE 
    `id` = IF(
                (((@CDpos:=LOCATE("cd", `string`)) OR TRUE) 
                AND ((@DEpos:=LOCATE("de", `string`)) OR TRUE))
                , `id`
                , `id`
            )
    AND @CDpos = (@DEpos - 1) -- always true if both strings are present
    AND @CDpos > 0;
```

| id | string | Position of "cd" | Position of "de" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcde | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | bcdef | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | cdefg | 1 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qmevgkagKg7mruDmfteHbk/2)