# User defined variables does not work on where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SET @a:=0
```

The below query works

```
SELECT *,@a:=@a+1 FROM article WHERE @a<=3
```

This query returns 3 rows
But when the query contains LEFT JOIN it does not work, returns all rows.

```
SELECT a.*,@a:=@a+1 FROM article a
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.aid=a.id
WHERE @a<=3
```

I don't understand why this query returns all rows

Comment: What is @a, can you make it clear more?

Comment: a user defined variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL user-defined variable in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984019/mysql-user-defined-variable-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT 3` would be a much clearer expression of what (it looks like) you are trying to do. That said, I have been known to borderline abuse session variables, and even I tend to balk at seeing them in WHERE clauses; it is generally inadvisable to cross clauses with them.

....though this could work for you:

```
SELECT a.*,@a:=@a+1 AS theAValue
FROM article a
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.aid=a.id
HAVING theAValue <=3
;
```

*HAVING is always processed after all the result fields have been calculated.*

Comment: i can not use limit cause i use it for pagination for articles

Comment: The `LIMIT [offset], [# rows]` form of `LIMIT` is often used for that.

Comment: and i can achieve this with other ways i am just curious why this is not working

Comment: My guess would be that in the first case, the conditions in the WHERE were checked after the results were retrieved, and in the second they were evaluated after the JOIN but before the result fields were calculated. One of the problems many people have with session variables is because the order of evaluation in MySQL can be fluid depending on context. (One way to verify would be to initialize @a to 4 and see if you get no rows in the second query.)